# Python discord bot "Command 'ban' is not found" error

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, command, bots

Guys im trying to make a discord bot and when I try to ban a member I get an error "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ban" is not found"

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')



@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Logged in as {0.user} ".format(client))



@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  print(f'{member} joined a server')


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  print(f'{member} left a server')

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been kick')



client.run('TOKEN')
```

I would be very happy if anyone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in a name to the `@commands.command()` decorator.

```py
@commands.command(name='ban', description='Bans a user')
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been kick')
```

And the first client variable isn't needed as you are declaring another client variable the line after it and it doesn't do much.

Comment: I did what you told me but it still doesn't work